# Election 2008 data files - how to know which candidate received the financial contribution?

Tags: file-format

I was trying to programmatically go through presidential campaign contributions to see which web 2.0 people contributed to which candidates. You can get the data file indiv08.zip on the site http://www.fec.gov/finance/disclosure/ftpdet.shtml#a2007_2008

I can parse out who contributed and how much they contributed, but I cannot figure out **who the contribution went to**. There seems to be some ID, but it does not match the candidate IDs in any other file I can find. If you can help with this, I think I could make a pretty nice page showing who contributed to which candidate.

*update -- I wonder if I just misunderstand this contribution system. Perhaps candidates cannot receive contributions at all, only committees? For example I see "C00431445OBAMA FOR AMERICA" received a lot of contributions. That makes it a bit more complicated then to associate those committees to candidates. Basically I want to know who supported Obama and who supported McCain.*

Comment: Note that indiv08.zip is a 68mb file and that the .txt file available alongside it doesn't appear to specify the benefactor of the contributions, so I'm not sure how you could tell who it went to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page 3 of the tutorial that is linked at the top of the page you liked to contains the column names including "Candidate Identification".

Comment: I saw that too but I don't see where to correlate it with the candidate list. 

As an example, here's the first record:

C00000042AMY P2893008274215 Hindman, Craig A.                 Palatine          IL60067

So the ID is IL60067. But the candidate file doesn't contain that.